# AWS VPC Peering Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, aws-vpc-peering, aws-networking

AOA Everyone, I am config. a VPC Peering connection.
I have

- 2 VPCs
- 3 Subnets
- 3 VMs

VPC-one has 2 Subnet associated (i.e. subnet-one & subnet-two)
VPC-two has 1 Subnet associated (i.e. subnet-one)
Each VM is connected to each Subnet

1. srvone (of subnet-one of VPC-one)
2. srvtwo (of subnet-two of VPC-one)
3. srvthree (of subnet-one of VPC-two)

So the problem I am facing is that the VMs in VPC-one are successfully communicating i.e. Ping.
But any VM from VPC-one is not ping to VM in VPC-two.

[VPC-one route-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3QES.png)

[VPC-two route-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QId6K.png)

[VPCone-to-VPCtwo Peering Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6icuA.png)

[VPCone-subnetone Security Group (Inbound) Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOrRt.png)

[VPCone-subnettwo Security Group (Inbound) Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JjQT.png)

[VPCtwo-subnetone Security Group (Inbound) Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhdy7.png)

[VPCone-subnetone Security Group (Outbound) Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZVeB.png)

[VPCone-subnettwo Security Group (Outbound) Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUBf0.png)

[VPCtwo-subnetone Security Group (Outbound) Rules][9]

VPCtwo-subnetone Security Group (Outbound) Rules is same as VPCone-subnetone SG (I don't have permission to add more than 8 links or add images)

Comment: "not ping to VM in VPC-two" - what's happening? A timeout, some connection refuse errors? How do you test that? Only pinging does not work? What about ssh?

Comment: I have only Allowed ICMP at ACL level. want to ping two VMs at two different VPCs.